# How to get client's IP address in Delphi RAD Server?

Tags: delphi, ems, rad-server

I have created a resource with `GetItem()`. RAD server calls `GetItem()` when the URL is accessed. Everything works.

The `GetItem()` procedure has 3 parameters:

```pascal
procedure GetItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; 
  const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; 
  const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
```

I have been through each of the classes looking for the client's IP address. The only IP I found is my server's own host IP, which is not useful.

Does RAD server make this information available?  I am using Delphi 10.2 Architect.

I have been through the library reference documentation. I have read through the PDFs that Embarcadaro published on creating a RAD server. I have tried searching the question on Google and Bing using different phrases.

I have written code to explore the different properties of the EMS classes.

I was expecting to find a property that contained the client's IP address, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Have you looked at `ARequest.ClientHost` ?

Comment: @JohnEasley The help for that in `EMS.ResourceAPI.TEndpointRequest Properties` (the type of ARequest) says: **ClientHost _public_ Retrieve the endpoint request client host IP**. Looks like the answer but was added with Delphi 11 Alexandria so not present in Delphi 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

> Does RAD server make this information available?

In Delphi 11 and later, you can use the [`TEndpointRequest.ClientHost`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/EMS.ResourceAPI.TEndpointRequest.ClientHost) property.

Unfortunately, that property did not exist yet in Delphi 10.2.  AFAIK, there is no other way to get the client IP in that version.